# Почему по клику не срабатывает метод focus()?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Показываю поле ввода (input) по клику и хочу, чтобы ставился фокус на него. но это почему-то не срабатывает и не могу понять в чём проблема.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // search
  $('.js-openSearch').on('click', (function() {

    $('.header-search').addClass('active');
    $('input').focus();

  }))

});
```

```css
.header-nav {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-nav::after {
  /*  content: ""; */
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(../images/searchButton.gif) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  right: -40px;
  top: calc(50% - 12px);
}

.nav.menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav.menu li {
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.nav.menu li.active a:before {
  height: 6px;
}

.nav.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav.menu li a:hover::before {
  height: 6px;
}

.nav.menu li a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #7f88bd;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.header-search {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 10%;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.header-search.active {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.header-search .search {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-search .search label {
  display: none;
}

.header-search .search input.search-query {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.header-search .search input.search-query::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans';
  color: #403b3b;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: .5;
}

.header-search .search input.search-query:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans';
  color: #403b3b;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: .5;
}

.header-search .search input.search-query::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans';
  color: #403b3b;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: .5;
}

.header-search .search input.search-query::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans';
  color: #403b3b;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: .5;
}

.header-search .search form {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.header-search .search input.button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 19px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 20;
}

.header-search-img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header-nav">
  <ul class="nav menu mod-list">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">О компании</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div src="/images/searchButton.gif" class="header-search-img js-openSearch" alt="Открыть поиск"></div>
  <div class="header-search">

    <div class="search">
      <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline" role="search">
        <label for="mod-search-searchword101" class="element-invisible">Искать...</label>
        <input name="searchword" id="mod-search-searchword101" maxlength="150" class="inputbox search-query input-medium" type="search" placeholder="Поиск...">
        <input type="image" alt="Искать" class="button" src="/images/searchButton.gif" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();">
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search">
        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_search">
        <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="105">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Блок с полем ввода появляется при клике на зеленый квадрат.

Comment: у меня подозрение что изза анимации, ето конечно костиль но попробуй так : `setTimeout(() => $('#mod-search-searchword101').focus(), 250);`

Comment: Да, так работает. Но дело вроде как не в анимации. Отключил transition и это не помогло.

Comment: я честно говоря без понятия почему так (